# How to store user data from .txt to work on it?

Tags: java, data-structures

Lets say I have a text file that contains

1-student ID

2-First Name

3- Last Name

4-  City

5- gender

They're separated by commas and every line of information has the same sequence as all the others.

I need to store the city, for instance, alone, so I can know if they're a good candidate for the trip (they specified specific cities).

Example from the text file:

1234567890, Sarah, Johnson, female, Oregon

1029384756, John, Pitt, male, Tampa

Which type of list do I use? And how can I separate each info in that list?

Answer (score 0):

Your file is basically CSV (comma separated values), so in your case I'd use the [OpenCsv](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv) library to parse the data.

If you don't want to use library you can read the lines `Files.lines(...)`
and then for each line use `line.split(',')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static class Student{
    private long studentId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String city;
    private String gender;


    public static Student parseLine(String line){
      String[] properties = line.split(", ");
      Student student = new Student();
      student.studentId = Long.parseLong(properties[0]);
      student.firstName = properties[1];
      student.lastName = properties[2];
      student.city = properties[3];
      student.gender = properties[4];
      return student;
    }

    public static Collection<Student> readFile(String path) throws IOException {

      return Files.lines(Paths.get(path)).map(Student::parseLine).collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
```

Comment: is  it not better to use a singly linked list? as the number of students is growing?

Comment: @Mep in java there is no such thing like a single linked list :(

Comment: @Mep look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist-in-java